# PHP, Regular Expression replacing only two characters, nothing more

Tags: php, regex

So I've been searching for a while now and I'm starting to go crazy. I'm obviously no RegEx expert, but I'm hoping you can help me out quick.

## The problem

I'm trying to write a regex line which will replace TWO dashes, no more, no less. One dash should be ignored, and three dashes should be ignored.

## What I've tried

I've come up with this, but it loops:

```
[--]{2}
```

And this gives me nothing:

```
^[--]{2}$
```

*Please* help me out! Thanks!

Comment: What about 4 dashes? e.g. 2 lots of 2 dashes?

Comment: Should be ignored. :) @ndn is correct, I just can't mark it as answered yet (question younger than 15 minutes).

Comment: In which case, yup *ndn*'s answer looks good to me :)

Comment: Would this (`--—--`) match or not? once, twice, or none?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Surround your *dashes* with [negative lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<!-)--(?!-)
```

This way, the *two dashes* will match only if there is *no dash* before or after them.

Comment: I think explanation is needed over here for future users

Comment: Future users should really read the link I gave. However, long story short: `(?<!something)` basically means *fail the match if **something** precedes the current position* and `(?!something)` means *fail the match if **something** follows the current position*.

Comment: Anyways +1 for answer... @ndn

Comment: Did you change anything in your answer? I get "Unknown modifier '-'" when I try it out now.

Comment: @MadMarvin, no I did not. You can see it working [here](https://regex101.com/r/dO1uL1/1).